# What happens to exceptions thrown from functions launched via std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

What happens to exceptions thrown from functions launched via `std::async`?

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void foo()
{
  std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl;
  throw std::runtime_error("Error");
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
    f.get();
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

MSVC gives me the following output:

```
1
foo()
Error
```

Is it right that such exceptions will be caught outside the function by calling the `get` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> [...] if the function `f` returns a value **or throws an exception**, it is stored in the shared state accessible through the `std::future` that `async` returns to the caller.

And in the reference about [`std::future::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get):

> If an exception was stored in the shared state referenced by the future (e.g. via a call to `std::promise::set_exception()`) then that exception will be thrown.

So yes, if your function throws an exception, that exception is basically deferred into the future and rethrown on `get()`.